# Sorting a list of tuples does not sort them actually

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, tuples

Lets say I have a dictionary like this:

```
a = {1:"a", 3:"c", 5:"e", 4:"d" ,2:"b", 6:"f", 7:"g"}
```

And I convert it to a list of tuples:

```
b = list(a.items())
```

Now, I want to sort the list based on the first value of the tuple. I have three ways of doing this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
b.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
```

```
b.sort(key=lambda x: x[::-1])
```

```
b = sorted(b, key=lambda t: (t[0]))
```

In either case, if I print `b` I get the sorted list:

```
print(b)

>>> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g')]
```

However, if I actually use `b` in a process, it turns out it is not sorted. I tested a few things but the current one I have at hand is this:

```
batch_count = len(b) // 3
batches = [[] for _ in range(batch_count)]
for index, vec in enumerate(b):
    batches[index % batch_count].append(vec)
```

This groups `b` to lists of at least 3. If I print `batches` however, I get the original order from `a`, with the exception of `7` which is expected.

```
print(batches)

>>> [[(1, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (5, 'e'), (7, 'g')], [(2, 'b'), (4, 'd'), (6, 'f')]]
```

Does anyone know why and how I can prevent this?

Comment: The output is exactly what you should get; the fact that your original `dict` had almost the same order (ignoring batch boundaries) is a coincidence.

Comment: What output *did* you expect? Grouping the elements of ``b`` into batches will naturally change their order. Note that each group is still properly ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same order. It's split by even/odd positions as a result of `index % batch_count`.

With a `batch_count` of 2, you have `index % 2`, which will alternate between `0` and `1`:

```
>>> [i % 2 for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

This has the end result of sticking even positions in the first sub-collection, and odds in the second.

Comment: I just tested with another dict and you are right! I have been spending about an hour on this and did not realize! I'm stupid! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. When in doubt, check your intermediate data. And for grouping, check out the recipes section in the `itertools` documentation. There may be an existing solution there that helps you. That's a great module.

Answer (score 1):

The output is normal. You can try it without sorting at all to see the difference.

```
batch_count = len(b) // 3
batches = [[] for _ in range(batch_count)]
for index, vec in enumerate(b):
    batches[index % batch_count].append(vec)
```

creates two sublists from your original list in your case, evens and odds. Each of them are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `grouper` function to split the list into a list of lists of size `n`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return ([e for e in t if e != None] for t in zip_longest(*args))

b = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g')]
batches = list(grouper(3, b))
print(batches)
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')], [(4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f')], [(7, 'g')]]
```

Comment: Although I like your thinking but the fact that it creates an iterable with only the first record having a value and then loop over it provides an unnecessary over head. Therefore, a for loop works faster. Albeit, very slightly. Still, a very good solution. Thanks!

Comment: @mnsr If you achieved the same after revising your for-loop, then yeah keep that.
This solution is more generic and works for every type of list, you want to group by a number. The overhead is negligible. Thanks for the upvote, cheers :)